# Parse 'complex' geojson through ORDS

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, geojson, oracle-ords, sdo

I'm having trouble generating a good geojson for tables that contain complex (Ordinate array 1005) geometry.

With my current approach I'm getting multiple ORA errors. Primarily ORA-13199 ERROR: wrong polygon.
[image: using the get_geojson()]

When I use a regular select geometry it seems to do just fine, I get proper json
[image: select geometry from table]

When I try to do this trick as part of my featureCollection it spits out SDO_GEOMETRY instead of Geojson.
[image]

I'm stuck, would appreciate help :)

Answer (score 0):

First at all the Oracle Spatial operations are based on correct defined Spatial data,
please try to check it with the SqlDeveloper:

<Right-Mouse-Click> - OnTable:
Select the validation function here:
[image: Select the validation function here -]

Comment: I ran validation. With default Tolerance 0.0005 I got no output. When lowing to 0.005 I get the following two kinds of output: 1: 13346 and 2: 13349 [Element <1>] [Ring <1>][Edge <24>][Edge <23>] or similar element, ring, edge or coordinate values.

Answer (score 0):

Use this SDO validation and rectifying from [Hans Viehmann and Albert Godfrind](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclespatial/validating-and-rectifying-spatial-data-in-the-oracle-database):

for your table & SDO column and with the 0.005 tolerance.

After this step check it finally:

`select rowid, geometry from my_geom_table where sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context(geometry, 0.005) != 'TRUE'`

~ if errors exists then use your GeoJSON handling only with the validated geometries:

`... where validate_geometry_with_context(shape, 0.005) = 'TRUE'`

Comment: hi fmatz, thanks for your suggestions. I've ran all validation and no errors arise. All geometry seems to be valid.

Comment: to clarify: when doing a simple: select (geometry column) from (tablename) I get valid geojson output for every single object in the table.